# What is a better way to process data?

Tags: json, oracle, file, csv

I have a table with around 10 million rows and 47 columns in Oracle. I do some processing on them before converting the data into JSON and transporting it to view layer. The processing is mostly select(*) grouping by various columns. This processing by select(*) is done 5 times with each time differently grouped columns. Now this is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to speed up the process?

I was thinking about pumping data from table into a csv file and processing it and then converting data into JSON to send it. Am I thinking into right direction. Please help.

The 5 queries I use are below for better understanding.

```
select sum(case when LOWER(column1) LIKE 'succeeded' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*))
from tablename where (TIME_STAMP between 'startTime' and 'endTime')

select column2,sum(case when LOWER(column1) LIKE 'succeeded' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*))
from tablename where (TIME_STAMP between 'startTime' and 'endTime') group by column2;

select column2,column3,sum(case when LOWER(column1) LIKE 'succeeded' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*))
from tablename where (TIME_STAMP between 'startTime' and 'endTime') group by column2,column3;

select column4,column3,sum(case when LOWER(column1) LIKE 'succeeded' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*))
from tablename where (TIME_STAMP between 'startTime' and 'endTime') group by column4,column3;

select column5,column4,column3,sum(case when LOWER(column1) LIKE 'succeeded' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*))
from tablename where (TIME_STAMP between 'startTime' and 'endTime') group by column5,column4,column3;
```

The result set is combined with the help of JSON and sent to View layer.

EDIT1: There are going to be multiple connections(5-20) to this database. Each connection executing these same queries.

Comment: Have you considered uing oracle's [`GROUPING SETS` expression](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#grouping_sets)? This would allow you to let the db combine the resultsets. Eg. `select column5,column4,column3,column2,sum(case when LOWER(column1) LIKE 'succeeded' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)) from tablename where (TIME_STAMP between 'startTime' and 'endTime') group by grouping sets((), (column2), (column3,column2) ,(column4,column3) ,(column5,column4,column3))`.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, will test and reply back. If there are multiple connections to this database performing this query for each of connections, will it effect select speed?

Comment: Have you considered adding indexes or other methods to speed up your `GROUP BY` performance?. It is highly unlikely that any home grown CSV processer is going to outperform Oracle, particularly when you add a step to export the data. Learn to use the tools you have.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am inserting around 20 thousand rows per 5 minutes in the same table and delete few thousand rows every 5 minutes but at a time average count of rows remain same. So if I use indexing I am worried insert will get a lot slower.

Comment: Is anything else of note about your selects? are those starttime and endtime values generally around the same window or could they be any time? I guess you don't have a dev environment to test indexes in. Do you have any existing indexes? You might find it has very little impact on insert performance.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Its like every 5 minutes I am inserting new data and at the same time selects work to bring in data which is 5-10 minutes older. So there is no sequential flow in inserts and selects, they may occur at same time.

Comment: No I mean the data you are selecting out - is it almost always something like `TIME_STAMP between 'a couple of days ago' and 'now'`, or could this be anytime i.e. `TIME_STAMP between '2 years ago' and '1 year ago'`. I'm not talking about the order of inserts/select I'm talking purely about the SELECT 'workload' - understanding the characteristics of your select statement.

Comment: The maximum difference between time stamp will be atmost 12 hours. But in between this time only there maybe 10-20 million rows in database.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have tested group sets and I think this may do the trick (along with indexing). It takes almost same time as 1 single query than writing those similar 5. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @collapsar I will test indexing and get back. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What I'm getting at is if you only ever select from the last week or so, then this might be a candidate for table partitioning. That will speed up inserts and selects. If you do find a hand coded group by algorithm that can outperform Oracle with appropriate indexes then I'd like to see it!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid if I am to do indexing here, should I create index on timestamp or timestamp and select columns, considering the amount of data

Comment: You generally don't put indexes on selected columns you put them on columns that are joined, filtered, grouped and ordered. Beyond that there is a lot more thought to be put into it indexes. But first understand that characteristics of your workload (do you only ever select the last weeks data? It seems to be a difficult question), and understand more about indexes. It's possible that a partitioned table will solve all your problems.